# How can I center buttons/text in a table column?

Tags: jquery, html, css, blueprint-css

When I say `<td style="padding: 50% 0 50% 0;" align="left"></td>` it spazes out and will get really large. I have tried a ton of things and with no good result. This shouldn't be that hard!!! (P.S. I am using the CSS blueprint framework but have cleared all of the table auto values...)

Comment: what about: `<td style='text-align:center;'></td>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<td style="vertical-align:middle" align="left"></td>`

or

`<tr valign="middle"><td align="left"></td</tr>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle" align="center"></td>
```